# Open Play Store with PendingIntent and NotificationManagerCompat

Tags: android, android-intent, android-notifications, android-pendingintent

Anyone know how to open Play Store with `Notification` and `PendingIntent`?

> I want to open Play Store with my app's page. 
>   Tried this one so far.

```
    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
            Uri.parse("market://details?id=" + a.getPackageName()));
    i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(a, 0, i, 0);

    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(a, "update")
            .setContentTitle(getStr(a, R.string.notify_update_title))
            .setContentText(getStr(a, R.string.notify_update_body))
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_notif)
            .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_DEFAULT)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

    NotificationManagerCompat managerCompat = NotificationManagerCompat.from(a);
    managerCompat.notify(UPDATE_NOTIF_ID, builder.build());
```

Comment: What happens, or doesn't happen?

Comment: @TheWanderer It just do nothing when the notification is clicked

Comment: Does the notification shade close as if it's trying to carry out an action?

Comment: The notification drawer closes but after that it does nothing.

Comment: Try changing your PendingIntent's request code to something other than 0.

Comment: Changed it to 1 it does not work

Comment: Try using the full Google Play URL format instead: `"https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=" + packageName`

Comment: What's your phone's android version?

Comment: Thanks @TheWanderer it was actually my fault i didn't observe the workflow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My bad. I was actually debugging on a very low-end smartphone API 16 that i have the Google Play compromised (uninstalled) because i need the Google Play Service up to date for Firebase.

> The surprising thing is that when i tap the notification it doesn't throw `ActivityNotFoundException` indicating that Google Play can't be found.

So there is a little caveat tested in API 16.

Thanks to all that helped appreciate it.